# Bootstrap3 Offcanvas fail

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

this is the example I am trying to replicate from the getboostrap examples.

http://pytools.webfactional.com/learn/bomar5/

here is my implementation. note: the other links are not adjusted from bootstrap 3-rc2 to the stable release so they will be all mangled layouts. the index.html file works, except for off canvas. I have looked at offcanvas.css, and even manually added

```
"style:-50%;"
```

to the div element that contained my sidebar-nav links but saw it only disappear. in the bootstrap example the nav remains on the side accessible via scrolling when it is at left:-50%;.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Create an example of your problem at : http://jsbin.com/

Comment: @TheDarkKnight http://jsbin.com/ARUFuMo/1/edit?html,css,output